# What could expender mean in the following context?

Tags: meaning, pronunciation-vs-spelling, non-native-english

I recently encountered the following text in a web page specification sheet:

> Most tables have expenders in each line

and

> There should be new tree named Item that is expended above type of
> Items

Although the verb "expend" exists in English, its meaning does not fit these sentences in the way it is conjugated, to the best of my knowledge.

What could the person who authored these sentences mean?

- expanders instead of expenders?
- expanded instead of expended?
- other?

Comment: We could guess they mean expand, but we don't really have enough to go on. It could equally be extend.

Comment: Odd use, but there could well be people who spend money on *Items* and *Type of Items*. Anyone paying for those expense items could be called *expenders*, by engineers or IBM, that is.

Comment: Without further context, I can only guess that this is in a somewhat technical document and that the "table" and "tree" are HTML-style entities that start out in a "collapsed" view and can be expanded to show their full contents.

Comment: Looks like it was written by someone who doesn't hear the vowel in **-an** with a native ear. I've heard many a native speaker of German pronounce that vowel as if it were **en**. Compare how in this AI imitation of Werner Herzog's voice (and that of  Slavoj Žižek),  "Herzog" says the word "animal" as "enimal" several pages into the imaginary discourse, "the hallucination of a slab of silicon":  https://www.infiniteconversation.com/

Comment: For the first sentence, could it be a specification sheet for building a dining room table? Wooden tables do have extensions/expanders, and a vertical line marks where the extension meets the table.

Comment: Can't you check the table itself? Or at least give some context as to what it's about?

Comment: Most likely collocation (from Oracle): A Table component displays hierarchical data using row expanders. https://vbcookbook.oracle.com/?page=shell&shell=row-expander&row-expander=row-expander-start&row-expander-start=recipe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it is a misprint for "exp**a**nders". See [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946925/how-to-programatically-expand-all-expanders-in-window)

> I've got a window with some expanders in it. When you open a expander there is some information inside it.
>
> What i need to do is to open all expanders with one button so
> everything inside them becomes visible. When everything is visible i
> want to print the full page.
>
> This is my code for expanding all expanders now:
>
> *lines of code omitted*
>
> The parent expanders do expand when the above code executes, The child
> expanders however remain unexpanded.

Thus "expanders" appear to be lines of code that, when activated, reveal more information on the screen.